# Babel: is it possible to transpile Async Await functions in browser without Webpack or Browserify?

Tags: async-await, babeljs, gulp-babel

I'm using **gulp-babel** with **babel 7** and the **plugin-transform-runtime**, but i get this error **'require is not defined'**, because it's a module and it's not working in browser.
So is it necessary Webpack or Browserify to make it works? or maybe i'm doing something wrong?
here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
  ]
}
```